# Power connector for small product

Tags: usb, connector, enclosure

I have a small (50mm x 30 x 12) battery-powered device to which I want to add a charging connector. I've been looking at panel mounted connectors such as this https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Switchcraft/PCL722AS?qs=fbkhFuCHoTZJW37LWjLsMA==, but curious if there aren't any better solutions for this. Current is relatively low (200 mA). USB seems like another good choice, but I am struggling to find one that can be panel mounted and sit relatively flush against the surface.

Thanks!

Comment: Small panel mounted connectors are typically round connectors, because they are more space efficient. USB connectors are not round, so they will be larger. Panel mount USB connectors typically have a full size USB female connector on the inside or a big wire lead with the USB male connector. What you're trying to find is a micro/mini usb panel mount connector with wire on the inside of the enclosure?

Comment: What voltage will it use?

Comment: you can mount a panel from the inside of the enclosure, so that it's flush, unless your "skin" is so thick that it keeps the usb plug from catching.

Comment: 5V

I've decided to go with a magnetic connector as they seem to tick all the boxes. Now trying to find a supplier and a way to fit it to the case

Answer (score 1):

That would be a perfect choice. It could however a bit bulky in size. Since you said that currently is relatively low, you could try using one of these:

[image]

These babies are straight panel mount female magnetic connectors. I fyou dont mind wasting a bit of money and having to make a special charger for this, your project would look "futuristic".

Anyways you could use this type of common mini-usb adapters too as they would be cheaper, although they are not perfectly panel mounted. tHEY WOULD DO THE JOB JUST FINE.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a good idea. Did some digging and found some Chinese companies that do this kind of magnetic connectors and cables for good prices: https://cletk.en.alibaba.com/product/60724170404-804809515/Usb_Cable_Charger_Magnetic_Dc_Power_Cable_Connectors_Power_Adapter.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.41413.12.141371b2bIt95e 

One think I'm unsure of is how I could fit this connector to the case. Some sort of resin maybe?

Comment: Yep, you gotta drill a hole and the and super glue the piece to it. I would suggest you drill a hole that is smaller than the piece, and then you scrape the hole to make it bigger until the piece fits in the hole really tight. After connecting the wires, you can just hot glue it from the inside. Not too clean, but works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a PCB, put a USB connector on it and be done with it.  If you're working from parts, it may work to get a USB micro B or USB C extender cable, and figure out how to hold the female end firmly into the case (if I did it both glue and screws would be involved).  Just cut off the male end and find the + and - wires.

(Note -- I don't know how an up-to-date USB device "tells" the charging device what voltage & current to use; it's up to you to do your research on this.  Or just use an older USB charger that can only do 5V -- if you're like everyone else in the developed world, your life is full of those)

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to go with a magnetic connector as they seem to tick all the boxes. Now trying to find a supplier and a way to fit it to the case